# Counting python method calls within another method

Tags: python, profiling

I'm actually trying doing this in Java, but I'm in the process of teaching myself python and it made me wonder if there was an easy/clever way to do this with wrappers or something.

I want to know how many times a specific method was called inside another method. For example:

```
def foo(z):
    #do something
    return result

def bar(x,y):
    #complicated algorithm/logic involving foo
    return foobar
```

So for each call to bar with various parameters, I'd like to know how many times foo was called, perhaps with output like this:

```
>>> print bar('xyz',3)
foo was called 15 times
[results here]
>>> print bar('stuv',6)
foo was called 23 times
[other results here]
```

edit: I realize I could just slap a counter inside bar and dump it when I return, but it would be cool if there was some magic you could do with wrappers to accomplish the same thing. It would also mean I could reuse the same wrappers somewhere else without having to modify any code inside the method.

Comment: in Java you can do it with an aspect, use *cflow* to check the calling method and *call* to match the method(s) to count, then implement around advice to increment a counter per matched method (maybe use a map of method signatures and counts)

Comment: or to just count invocations, simply match *execution* instead of using *cflow* and *call*

Comment: I was going to point you to a Pyhon code coverage tool (coverage.py), because surely it must contain helpful techniques for what you want to do. But then the author himself (Hi Ned!) answered your question. You might want to look at http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/ anyway.

Comment: Hi df! Ironically I didn't mention coverage.py...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sounds like almost the textbook example for decorators!

```
def counted(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.called += 1
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.called = 0
    wrapper.__name__ = fn.__name__
    return wrapper

@counted
def foo():
    return

>>> foo()
>>> foo.called
1
```

You could even use another decorator to automate the recording of how many times a function is called inside another function:

```
def counting(other):
    def decorator(fn):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            other.called = 0
            try:
                return fn(*args, **kwargs)
            finally:
                print '%s was called %i times' % (other.__name__, other.called)
        wrapper.__name__ = fn.__name__
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@counting(foo)
def bar():
    foo()
    foo()

>>> bar()
foo was called 2 times
```

If `foo` or `bar` can end up calling themselves, though, you'd need a more complicated solution involving stacks to cope with the recursion. Then you're heading towards a full-on profiler...

Possibly this wrapped decorator stuff, which tends to be used for magic, isn't the ideal place to be looking if you're still ‘teaching yourself Python’!

Comment: I am getting `foo was called 0 times` in the second example.

Comment: after my brain parses the second example, it returns 0 as well (see comment above from Krzystztof Slowinisky)

Answer (score 7):

This defines a decorator to do it:

```
def count_calls(fn):
    def _counting(*args, **kwargs):
        _counting.calls += 1
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    _counting.calls = 0
    return _counting

@count_calls
def foo(x):
    return x

def bar(y):
    foo(y)
    foo(y)

bar(1)
print foo.calls
```

Comment: So, do all decorated functions share this global variable? It looks like they do. >>> print CALLS
2
>>> @count_calls
... def foobar(y):
...     return y
...
>>> foobar(1)
1
>>> print CALLS
1

Comment: I changed the code to keep the count on a function attribute, so now they'll be kept separate.

Comment: This works, but it won't count how many times ONLY bar has called foo.  You'd have to add some logic to determine the caller of the foo, which I'm guessing is possible, but I don't know offhand how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Ned, this is really close. But I think Triptych is right. I was thinking of something more like a wrapper on bar that took foo as a parameter. The bar wrapper would then wrap foo to count calls, and print the count after bar had executed.

Comment: I don't have complete code, but this might be helpful: sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name  is the name of your caller.

Comment: I think I got the issue of only counting calls by bar in my new version.  Wasn't sure if sys._getframe should be used vs. inspect because of the underscore name, so I did it with inspect to show that anyway.

Answer (score 2):

After your response - here's a way with a decorator factory...

```
import inspect

def make_decorators():
    # Mutable shared storage...
    caller_L = []
    callee_L = []
    called_count = [0]
    def caller_decorator(caller):
        caller_L.append(caller)
        def counting_caller(*args, **kwargs):
            # Returning result here separate from the count report in case
            # the result needs to be used...
            result = caller(*args, **kwargs)
            print callee_L[0].__name__, \
                   'was called', called_count[0], 'times'
            called_count[0] = 0
            return result
        return counting_caller

    def callee_decorator(callee):
        callee_L.append(callee)
        def counting_callee(*args, **kwargs):
            # Next two lines are an alternative to
            # sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name mentioned by Ned...
            current_frame = inspect.currentframe()
            caller_name = inspect.getouterframes(current_frame)[1][3]
            if caller_name == caller_L[0].__name__:
                called_count[0] += 1
            return callee(*args, **kwargs)
        return counting_callee

    return caller_decorator, callee_decorator

caller_decorator, callee_decorator = make_decorators()

@callee_decorator
def foo(z):
    #do something
    return ' foo result'

@caller_decorator
def bar(x,y):
    # complicated algorithm/logic simulation...
    for i in xrange(x+y):
        foo(i)
    foobar = 'some result other than the call count that you might use'
    return foobar


bar(1,1)
bar(1,2)
bar(2,2)
```

And here's the output (tested with Python 2.5.2):

```
foo was called 2 times
foo was called 3 times
foo was called 4 times
```

Comment: I realize I could just add a counter somewhere inside the bar method and just print it out when I return, but I was wondering if this was possible without actually changing any code within bar.

Comment: Ah - gotcha - I edited to put in a new answer with a factory to make both decorators that cooperate.