# Python - scope of wrapping functions

Tags: python, closures, wrapper

The goal is to wrap a function or method and carry data around with the wrapper that's unique to the wrapped function.

As an example -  let's say I have object `myThing` with method `foo`. I want to wrap `myThing.foo` with `myWrapper`, and (as an example) I want to be able to count the number of times `myThing.foo` is actually called.

So far, the only method I've found to be effective is to just add an attribute to the object -- but this feels a little bit clumsy.

```
class myThing(object):
    def foo(self):
        return "Foo called."

def myWrap(some_func):
    def _inner(self):
        #a wild kludge appears!
        try:
            self.count += 1
        except AttributeError:
            self.count = 0
        return some_func(self)
    return _inner

Stick = myThing()
myThing.foo = myWrap(myThing.foo)
for i in range(0, 10):
    Stick.foo() ##outputs "Foo called." 10 times

Stick.count # the value of Stick.count
```

So, this achieves the goal, and in fact if there are multiple instances of `myThing` then each one 'tracks' its own self.count value, which is part of my intended goal.  However, I am not certain that adding an attribute to each instance of `myThing` is the best way to achieve this. If, for example, I were to write a wrapper for a function that wasn't part of an object or class, adding attributes to an object that isn't there won't do anything.

Maybe there is a hole in my understanding of what's actually happening when a method or function is wrapped. I do know that one can maintain some kind of static data within a closure, as with the following example:

```
def limit(max_value):
    def compare(x):
        return x > max_value
    return compare

isOverLimit = limit(30)
isOverLimit(45) #returns True
isOverLimit(12) #returns False

alsoOver = limit(20)
alsoOver(25) # returns True
isOverLimit(25) # returns False
```

The second example proving that it's not simply modifying the original instance of `limit`, and that `isOverLimit` continues to act as it did before the second `alsoOver` is created. So I get the sense that there's a way for the wrapper to carry an incremental variable around with it, and that I'm just missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is a dupe of [Counting python method calls within another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301735/counting-python-method-calls-within-another-method)

The short answer is to use a decorator on the method/function you want to count, and have the decorator store the counter as a function attribute. See the answers in the question I linked.

Comment: I think you're right! I'm going to play with this.