# Python - disposable ifs

Tags: python, algorithm

While writing state machines to analyze different types of text data, independent of language used (VBA to process .xls contents using arrays/dictionaries or PHP/Python to make SQL insert queries out of .csv's) I often ran into neccesity of something like

```
boolean = False
while %sample statement%:
    x = 'many different things'
    if boolean == False:
        boolean = True
    else:
        %action that DOES depend on contents of x
             that need to do every BUT first time I get to it%
```

Every time I have to use a construction like this, I can't help feeling **noob**. Dear algorithmic gurus, can you assure me that it's the only way out and there is nothing more *elegant*? Any way to specify that some statement should be "burnt after reading"? So that some stupid boolean is not going to be checked each iteration of the loop

Comment: Maybe see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626917/how-to-tell-when-a-method-is-called-for-first-time-of-many) (It's not quite the same as your question. There are probably others out there closer.)

Comment: @dwn things discussed there are obvious to me and, unfortunately, **NOT** helping at all. I'll edit my question now to point out that the action on the last line **depends** on preceeding code inside the loop

Comment: (OT) Read the title as "Python - disposable lies". A pretty sinister one!

Comment: OTOH, these awkward constructs do look like "lies" (i.e. feel very wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things that come across as slightly "noob" about this style are:

- Comparing a boolean variable to `True` or `False`. Just write `if <var>` or `if not <var>`. (I'll ignore the `=` vs `==` as a typo!)
- Not giving the boolean variable a good name. I know that here `boolean` is just a placeholder name, but in general using a name like `first_item_seen` rather than something generic can make the code a *lot* more readable:

  ```
  first_item_seen = False
  while [...]:
      [...]
      if first_item_seen:
          [...]
      else:
          first_item_seen = True
  ```

Another suggestion that can work in some circumstances is to base the decision on another variable that naturally conveys the same state. For instance, it's relatively common to have a variable that contains `None` for the first iteration, but contains a value for later iterations (e.g. the result so far); using this can make the code slightly more efficient and often slightly clearer.

Comment: I firstly didnt think about asking *specifically* about python, wrote "pseudocode" that didnt belong to any specific language, and thats why I named boolean variable "boolean" and used a = instead of ==.

Comment: Of course, one other alternative is to define functions f0() and f1(), and then write ... f0() while [...]: x=BLAH f0() f1(x)

Comment: Thanks for the idea with checking some other related things, it's not universal, but is *actually more elegant* than using an extra boolean. If nothing better is suggested, I guess I'll acept that

Comment: @dwn Sorry, I did not get your point at all. What's that sample code you wrote? It doesn't explain anything to me! How will that *simplify* anything?

Comment: @mekkanizer Depends on the actual code if it will simplify anything. It would at least not require a boolean, "So that some stupid boolean is not going to be checked each iteration of the loop".

Comment: @mekkanizer Basically I'm just saying one option is to break it into two functions, and run one before the loop

Comment: @dwn I see what you are saying. HOW running something before the loop can help me if the things I want to do are related to content being defined/changed INSIDE the loop? There is just no sense in doing some extra actions before the loop, it's not simplifying, it's making more complex!

Comment: @mekkanizer You can pass your variable into the function. I didn't say it simplified it; I have no idea what your code is.

Comment: @dwn What a strange suggestion even NOT regarding the code. Look. X is passed into function every iteration of the loop and some decision is made over there **or** some decision is made inside the loop. Passing it into function only makes things more complex. Functions are generally used to code some repeating pattern once. Here I see no reasons to use functions (pls tell me at least one?), I only see reasons *against*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, I'd try something like

```
x = 'many different things'
while %sample statements%:
    x = 'many different things'
    action_that_depends_on_x()
```

It is almost equivalent; the only difference is that in your version the loop body could be never executed (hence `x` never being computed, hence no side effects of computing `x`), in my version it is always computed at least once.

Comment: No. You got me wrong. Again. I compute contents of `x` inside loop and need to operate them *inside* loop, every BUT first time I get to the %use_x_for_some_action% part