# Python Logging - How To Check If Logger Is Empty

Tags: python, logging, is-empty

I just implemented logging in my app, and I'd like to know if there's a method to check if a logger is empty or not.

What I have in mind is to set two handlers in my script:

- One for console with level `WARNING`
- One for file with level `DEBUG`

At the end of the script, I need to check if `CONSOLE` logger is not empty. This means that during the run, some messages with `level >= WARNING` were logged, and in this case I'd like to send the log file with debug level thru `smtp`to my mailbox.

Is this check possible inside the `python` script itself, without shell redirection to file?

Comment: One thought is to write a custom hander for the console that, if it is ever called, uses `atexit.register` to schedule code that e-mails the log file.

Answer (score 4):

There's a general purpose way to count the number of times a function was called using decorators you can check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301735/counting-python-method-calls-within-another-method)

If you wrap this decorator around class calls you are interested in you could find out how many times each member function was called, something like this:

```
def counted(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.called += 1
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.called = 0
    wrapper.__name__ = fn.__name__
    return wrapper

class MyLogger(logging.Logger, object):

    @counted
    def info(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyLogger, self).info(*args, **kwargs)

    @counted
    def warning(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyLogger, self).warning(*args, **kwargs)
```

Next just set up your logger like any other and use it as you normally would:

```
log = my_logger.MyLogger('test_logger')
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(ch)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

>>> log.info('no big deal')
no big deal
>>> log.info('harmless message')
harmless message
>>> log.warning('oh no')
oh no

>>> log.info.called
2
>>> log.warning.called
1
```

You would need to decorate all of the classes you wanted counted, so exception, debug etc.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I'll try it.
This seems to be an elegant solution too.

Comment: I tried that def init_logger(lid: str):
    log = MyLogger(str(lid))
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log.addHandler(ch)
    log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return log


log1 = init_logger(1)
log2 = init_logger(2)

log1.info("INFO 1")
print(log2.info.called) --> 1 Why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I forgot to complete this thread.
Following Mike's idea, I came up with something like this :

in a module called logset.py :

```
def counted(fn):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.count += 1
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.count = 0
    wrapper.__name__ = fn.__name__
    return wrapper

class MyLogger(logging.Logger):

    def __init__(self, name=None, level=logging.NOTSET):
        super(MyLogger, self).__init__(name, level)

    @counted
    def info(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyLogger, self).info(*args, **kwargs)

    @counted
    def warning(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyLogger, self).warning(*args, **kwargs)

    @counted
    def critical(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyLogger, self).warning(*args, **kwargs)

    @counted
    def error(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyLogger, self).warning(*args, **kwargs)

    def logfile(self):
        for h in self.handlers:
            if hasattr(h, 'baseFilename'):
                return h.baseFilename

    def empty(self):
        if self.warning.count or self.critical.count or self.error.count:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def status(self):
        msg = "WARNINGS:%s ERRORS:%s CRITICAL:%s" % (self.warning.count, self.error.count, self.critical.count)
        return msg

def addLogFile(logger, filepath):

    handler = logging.FileHandler(filepath, "w", encoding=None, delay="true")
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s\t: %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

def addLogConsole(logger):

    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s\t: %(message)s")
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

def myLog(level=None):

    if not LOGGER.handlers:
        # "Adding Handlers..."
        addLogConsole(LOGGER)
        addLogFile(LOGGER, '#YOUR LOG FILE#')

    return LOGGER

LOGGER = MyLogger("root")
```

In my app's start file :

```
from logset import myLog
.
.
. # Initialize the log
root = myLog()
.
.
. # Do something in your app and at end check :

if not root.empty():
    print "\nProgram has logged some errors, check log : %s" % root.logfile()
    print root.status()
    # now I can send root.logfile() via smtp for further examination
```

You can repeat the import in every module that needs logging, it always refers to the same logger object:

```
from logset import myLog
log = myLog()
.
.
.
log.info("Adding something")
log.debug("this var has value : %s" % value)
```

Thank you for your help and attention.
Enrico