# python: how to count the number of times my recursion function executes?

Tags: python, recursion

Suppose I have a binary search tree `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]`

If I run the following function, I want to know how many times the recursion function executes(in the following example, it is 31)

```
def loopBST(root):
    if not root:
        return
    loopBST(root.left)
    loopBST(root.right)
```

I can get this by create a global variable

```
global ind 
ind = 0
def loopBST(root):
    global ind
    ind += 1
    if not root:
        return
    loopBST(root.left)
    loopBST(root.right)
loopBST(bsttree)
```

The variable `ind` will be 31.

The question is, how can I make this `ind`inside the `dfs` function rather than creating the global variable?

Comment: Can you please use codeblock formatting? Do four spaces of indentation for every line you have code and it will look a lot cleaner.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting python method calls within another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301735/counting-python-method-calls-within-another-method)

Comment: [Counting function calls](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Counting_function_calls)

Answer (score 6):

You could *return* the number of executions:

```
def loopBST(root):
    if not root:
        return 1
    return 1 + loopBST(root.left) + loopBST(root.right)
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I see you from leetcode. In fact this question is from the question I am practicing in leetcode. I know I can solve this by put the dfs inside a `class` and set up a `global count variable` inside the `class` to finish this job.   I am wondering if there is any way I can put that count variable as a parameter of the `dfs` function. Can I do this in the recursion fuction? I can create a `dfs` parameter  called `temp` list and append a value to that `temp` list once there is a recursion run.

Comment: Which question is it there? I don't think leetcode ever asked to count function calls...

Comment: for example, q230. to return kth smallest of bst. You have fancy way to solve it. I try to start from stupid way: goes to the left lowest leaf, and then goes up, if I goes up k(my i==k), I will get the answer. My stupid code is like ```def kthsmall2(root, k):
    if not root:
        return
    def dfs(node, i, k):
        i += 1
        if not node:
            return
        dfs(node.left, i, k)
        if i == k:
            return node.val
        dfs(node.right, i, k)
        return i
    print dfs(root, 0, k)```

Answer (score 5):

You could use a parameter.

```
def loopBST(root, times=0):
    times += 1
    if not root:
        return times
    times = loopBST(root.left, times=times)
    times = loopBST(root.right, times=times)
    return times
loopBST(bsttree)
```

Comment: No problem! I missed something too; I forgot to return `times` at the end of the function. Edited.

Comment: Oh, good, so I was somewhat right after all :-P. I wish they had provided usable testing data instead of an unclear list, then none of this would've happened...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to rewrite your recursive function, you could also decorate it in a function that counts it using a counter of some sort. Example of an implementation:

**UPDATE:** I've changed the answer, but the old answer is kept at the end of the answer **//UPDATE**

Assume here that you have some recursion functions in some_module.py:

```
# From some_module.py
def factorial(x):
    return factorial(x-1)*x if x > 1 else 1

def cumsum(x):
    return cumsum(x-1) + x if x > 1 else 1

def loopBST(root):
    # ... your code
```

And you want to apply the decorator to count how many recursions ran. Here, the code is performed inside `some_function()` to show that you don't have to keep the count variable(s) in the global scope. (See comments) (Also, the recursive functions are still in global space)

```
# Main file:
from functools import wraps, partial
from collections import defaultdict
# import the two recursion functions from some_module.py
from some_module import cumsum, factorial, loopBST


def some_function():
    global factorial, cumsum, loopBST

    def counting_recursion(fn, counter):
        @wraps(fn)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            counter[fn.__name__] += 1
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    counters = defaultdict(int)

    my_deco = partial(counting_recursion, counter=counters)
    factorial = my_deco(factorial)
    cumsum = my_deco(cumsum)
    loopBST = my_deco(loopBST)

    print(factorial(3))
    # 6
    print(cumsum(5))
    # 15

    factorial_count = counters[factorial.__name__]
    cumsum_count = counters[cumsum.__name__]
    loopBST_count = counters[loopBST.__name__]  # Equals 0: were not called in my example

    print('The "{}" function ran {} times'.format(factorial.__name__, factorial_count))
    print('The "{}" function ran {} times'.format(cumsum.__name__, cumsum_count))
    # The "factorial" function ran 3 times
    # The "cumsum" function ran 5 times
```

A few modifications/variations:

Instead of using `my_deco = partial(counting_recursion, counter=counters)`, the recursive functions could be decorated directly:

```
cumsum = counting_recursion(cumsum, counter=counters)
factorial = counting_recursion(factorial, counter=counters)
loopBST = counting_recursion(loopBST, counter=counters)
```

Instead of using `fn.__name__` to identify the called function, the `counting_recursion`-function could be rewritten as:

```
def counting_recursion(fn, counter):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        counter[wrapper] += 1
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Then, to read the number from the `counters` dictionary:

```
factorial_count = counters[factorial]
cumsum_count = counters[cumsum]
loopBST_count = counters[loopBST]
```

If you want to read more about wrapping functions, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/25827070/1144382 and the docs on [wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)

**OLD EXAMPLE:**

```
from functools import wraps, partial

class Counter:
    def __init__(self, start_count=0):
        self._counter = start_count

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._counter)

    def count(self):
        self._counter += 1

counter = Counter()

def counting_recursion(fn, counter):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        counter.count()
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

my_deco = partial(counting_recursion, counter=counter)

@my_deco
def factorial(x):
    return factorial(x-1)*x if x > 1 else 1

print(factorial(3))
# 6

print('The {} function ran {} times'.format(factorial.__name__, counter))
# The factorial function ran 3 times
```

To implement this in your case, just make some counter and decorate your function:

```
@my_deco
def loopBST(root):
    # ...

print(counter._counter)
# prints number of counts
```

Of course, you don't have to make a `Counter`-class to call `counter.count()` on, you could also have a dictionary of counters, e.g. `counts[loopBST] += 1` or just an array with a single element `count_list[0] += 1`. (*see the code example at top of this answer*) (The entire point is to "hide" the value in a reference that is not rewritten when the variable is reassigned, which is why just an integer count `count += 1` won't work.)

Comment: I like this solution with decorator. It might be a good idea to modify the decorator so that we can avoid the global variable for the empty dictionary and may be importing the partial function

Comment: I see, thanks for follow up, I will update my answer when I get back to my computer.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try with instance of a class, this way it probably is cleaner than having keyword argument. Not to mention that you can store additional data in instance.

This is a Python 2.7 class.

```
class LoopBST(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.ind = 0

    def __call__(self, root):
        self.ind += 1

        if not root:
            return

        self(root.left)
        self(root.right)

loopBST = LoopBST()

loopBST(bstree)

print loopBST.ind
```

Comment: Encapsuling such simple task like this inside a class doesn't seem to be a very pythonic way.