# How to know how many times a method has been called from a specific method

Tags: python

I have a case, let's say:

```
class A:
    def store():
        name = 'unknown'
        for name in inspect.stack():
            if 'method_a' in name:
                print('Called x times from method A')
            if 'method_b' in name:
                print('Called x times from method B')

class B:
    def __init__():
        self.a = A()

    def method_a():
        self.a.store()
        self.a.store()

    def method_b():
        self.a.store()
        self.a.store()
        self.a.store()
```

So, I'm interested to know how many times has the `store` method been called from `methodA` and from `methodB` from class `B`. I can't modify class `B`, the logic should be implemented only from `store` method of class `A`.

Does the `inspect` library offer such a feature? Or, I can extract the result I want in some other way?

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301735/counting-python-method-calls-within-another-method) should give you a head start on how to build this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I need the exact functionality as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1301926/11727882
But, in my case I have to add `@counted(store)` to the `method_a` and `method_b`. Is there a way to achieve the desired functionality without touching class `B`?

Comment: Yes, but you have to take the ideas presented there (read the other answers too) and build it.